# How to create one form both for parent and child object in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a Project object whose only parameter(besides :id) is :project_name. 
The child of that object is ProjectDescription object whose parameters are :project_id and :description. How to code a form wich creates a project with corresponding description without Rails giving out any errors?

Comment: why not making the description a column of Project?

Comment: Look for a "nested forms" tutorial to do this. But I agree with @Castilho, why not just make description a column on Project?

Comment: @Castilho , I know, but I'm learning Rails and want to cover as much as I can. Also the idea was, to hide project descriptions and toggle them on/off, so I made them a separate object with visibility column as a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Castilho commented, it sounds like you could refactor your database schema and not have to worry about this, but...

What you're looking for is called a nested attributes form:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Ryan Bates did a great screencast on this topic:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1